# Create custom arrow view

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

In my android project , I'm trying to create view like this

[image: image2]

its not so hard to create something close using bezier path

but what I need is the ability to resize the width of this view without affecting the left side of the arrow ( it will only become smaller arrow like this)

[image: image2]

What is the best practice ?

Comment: create 9 patch image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 patch image. NinePatch images are PNG images in which we can mark the parts of an image that can be stretched. You can use the WYSIWIG draw9patch.jar tool inside your Android SDK /tools folder to create 9 patch image.

see [Android developer user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)

This is also a good tool: [click here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repo to get this view https://github.com/imranhsn/ArrowShape

```
  <com.example.arrowshape.shapes.BubbleView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:shape_bubble_borderRadius="0dp"
        app:shape_bubble_arrowPosition="left"
        app:shape_bubble_arrowHeight="60dp"
        app:shape_bubble_arrowWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        // your child layout

</com.example.arrowshape.shapes.BubbleView>
```

[image]